# Can I optimize this PowerShell parser

Tags: powershell

I've written a PowerShell script to read delimited files and traverse them line by line.
This script saves attribute values into variables and writes those values into a file when it meets the string end.

Is there a way to optimize this script for more speed, assuming I don't have the .Net framework installed?

```
rm storage.txt
$job_counter = 0;
$att_counter = 0;

foreach ($line in Get-Content .\a.txt) {
    if ($line -match '^end$') {
        $job_counter++;
    }
}

echo "File has $job_counter jobs"

$job_counter = 0;

foreach ($line in Get-Content .\a.txt) {
    if ($line -notmatch '^end$') {
        $line_header = ($line.Split(":")[0])
        $line_value = ($line.Split(":")[1])
        switch ($line_header) {
            insert_job      {$insert_job      = $line_value.trim();break}
            job_type        {$job_type        = $line_value.trim();break}
            command         {$command         = $line_value.trim();break}
            machine         {$machine         = $line_value.trim();break}
            owner           {$owner           = $line_value.trim();break}
            permission      {$permission      = $line_value.trim();break}
            date_conditions {$date_conditions = $line_value.trim();break}
            days_of_week    {$days_of_week    = $line_value.trim();break}
            start_times     {$start_times     = $line_value.trim();break}
            description     {$description     = $line_value.trim();break}
            std_out_file    {$std_out_file    = $line_value.trim();break}
            std_err_file    {$std_err_file    = $line_value.trim();break}
            alarm_if_fail   {$alarm_if_fail   = $line_value.trim();break}
            end             {$end             = $line_value.trim();break}
            box_name        {$box_name        = $line_value.trim();break}
            condition       {$condition       = $line_value.trim();break}
            run_window      {$run_window      = $line_value.trim();break}
            n_retrys        {$n_retrys        = $line_value.trim();break}
            term_run_time   {$term_run_time   = $line_value.trim();break}
            box_terminator  {$box_terminator  = $line_value.trim();break}
            job_terminator  {$job_terminator  = $line_value.trim();break}
            min_run_alarm   {$min_run_alarm   = $line_value.trim();break}
            max_run_alarm   {$max_run_alarm   = $line_value.trim();break}
            profile         {$profile_name    = $line_value.trim();break}
        }
        $att_counter++;
    } else {
        $job_counter++
        echo "encountered job number $job_counter, it has $att_counter attributes"
        echo "'$insert_job','$job_type','$command','$machine','$owner','$permission','$date_conditions','$days_of_week','$start_times','$description','$std_out_file','$std_err_file','$alarm_if_fail','$end','$box_name','$condition','$run_window','$n_retrys','$term_run_time','$box_terminator','$job_terminator','$min_run_alarm','$max_run_alarm','$profile_name'" >>storage.txt

        Clear-Variable -Name "insert_job";
        Clear-Variable -Name "job_type";
        Clear-Variable -Name "command";
        Clear-Variable -Name "machine";
        Clear-Variable -Name "owner";
        Clear-Variable -Name "permission";
        Clear-Variable -Name "date_conditions";
        Clear-Variable -Name "days_of_week";
        Clear-Variable -Name "start_times";
        Clear-Variable -Name "description";
        Clear-Variable -Name "std_out_file";
        Clear-Variable -Name "std_err_file";
        Clear-Variable -Name "alarm_if_fail";
        Clear-Variable -Name "end";
        Clear-Variable -Name "box_name";
        Clear-Variable -Name "condition";
        Clear-Variable -Name "run_window";
        Clear-Variable -Name "n_retrys";
        Clear-Variable -Name "term_run_time";
        Clear-Variable -Name "box_terminator";
        Clear-Variable -Name "job_terminator";
        Clear-Variable -Name "min_run_alarm";
        Clear-Variable -Name "max_run_alarm";
        Clear-Variable -Name "profile_name";

        $att_counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure about the performance effect, but instead of a switch-case, you could use a hashtable and the header as key.

Comment: How exactly do you intend to run PowerShell in the first place without the .Net framework installed? Anyway, please show a sample of the file you're trying to parse, and we may be able to provide suggestions, although I think [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would generally be a better place for the question.

Comment: Unless `a.txt` is very large I'd read it only once into a variable. Also `a.txt` looks like the output in list format of another cmdlet, it may be easier to process the output in csv format, or split the file first after the `end` line and use `ConvertFrom-StringData` after replacing the `:` with an equal sign.

Comment: @LotPings Generally speaking you're correct about (not) reading `a.txt` multiple times. However, if the file is small it shouldn't make that much of a difference whether it's being read once or twice. And if it's big the OP shouldn't be using a `foreach` loop in the first place.

Comment: Micro-optimisation: Don't split `$line` twice. Split it once into a variable and get header and value from that.

Comment: To elaborate on @PalleDues hint, to **NOT** split also on possible colons in `$line_value` limit the splits and directly assign to variables: `$line_header,$line_value = $line.split(':',2)`

Answer (score 1):

There are good pointers in the comments and in [TessellatingHeckler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54820312/45375), but let me attempt to pull it all together with additional speed improvements - see the comments in the code.

```
rm storage.txt
$job_counter = 0
$att_counter = 0

# Read all lines into memory up front, using the .NET framework directly
# which is much faster than using Get-Content.    
$allLines = [IO.File]::ReadAllLines("$PWD/a.txt")

# Count the lines that contain 'end' exactly to determine
# the number of jobs.
$job_counter = ($allLines -eq 'end').Count

"File has $job_counter jobs"

$job_counter = 0

# Initialize the hashtable whose entries will contain the values
# (rather than individual variables).
$values = [ordered] @{}

# Use a `switch` statement to process the lines, which is generally
# faster than a `foreach` loop.
switch ($allLines) {
  'end' {  # Use string equality (not regex matching), which is faster.
    $job_counter++
    "encountered job number $job_counter, it has $att_counter attributes"
    # Write the values to 
    "'$($values.insert_job)','$($values.job_type)','$($values.command)','$($values.machine)','$($values.owner)','$($values.permission)','$($values.date_conditions)','$($values.days_of_week)','$($values.start_times)','$($values.description)','$($values.std_out_file)','$($values.std_err_file)','$($values.alarm_if_fail)','$($values.end)','$($values.box_name)','$($values.condition)','$($values.run_window)','$($values.n_retrys)','$($values.term_run_time)','$($values.box_terminator)','$($values.job_terminator)','$($values.min_run_alarm)','$($values.max_run_alarm)','$($values.profile)'" >>storage.txt
    # Clear the values from the hashtable.
    $values.Clear()
  }
  default { 
    # Split the line at hand into field name and value...
    $fieldName, $value = $_ -split ':', 2, 'SimpleMatch'
    # ... and add an entry for the pair to the hashtable.
    $values.$fieldName = $value.trim()
    $att_counter++
  }
}
```

Note: The solution above doesn't validate the field names found in the input file; extra work would be needed for that.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Content .\a.txt` is slow, replace it with `[system.io.file]::ReadAllLines('c:\full\path\to\file\a.txt')` which is a lot faster.

Get rid of the entire first loop, and don't echo how many jobs there are at all. If you must do that, push the loop down the stack and use `$jobCount = ($LinesLoadedOnce -match '^end$').Count` and use `-match` to do the looping / filtering instead of `foreach`.

Instead of calling `Clear-Variable` many times per line of text file and incurring the overhead of starting a cmdlet many times, call it once and pass it an array of names to clear, e.g. `Clear-Variable -Name "insert_job", "job_type", "command", ..`.

Instead of using `>>storage.txt` which opens and closes the txt file once per line, gather the output in an array, and write it once to a file with `set-content`

```
$results = foreach ($line in [system.io.file]::ReadAllLines('c:\full\path\to\file\a.txt'))
{
    #code here

    "'$insert_job','$job_type','$command', .."

}

$results | Set-Content -Path storage.txt
```

The rest gets more dependent on the format of your file, how big it is, if there are lines you are skipping, but it could become something like:

```
$headers = @(
    'insert_job'
    'job_type'
    'command'
    'machine'
    'owner'
    'permission'
    'date_conditions'
    'days_of_week'
    'start_times'
    'description'
    'std_out_file'
    'std_err_file'
    'alarm_if_fail'
    'end'
    'box_name'
    'condition'
    'run_window'
    'n_retrys'
    'term_run_time'
    'box_terminator'
    'job_terminator'
    'min_run_alarm'
    'max_run_alarm'
    'profile'
)

$headerRegex = "^($($headers -join '|'))\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*$"

$data = [ordered]@{}
foreach($h in $headers) { $data[$h] = $null }

$results = foreach ($line in [system.io.file]::ReadAllLines('c:\full\path\to\file\a.txt')) {

    if ($line -match $headerRegex) {
        $data[$matches[1]] = $matches[2]
    }
    elseif ($line -eq 'end') {
        [PSCustomObject]$data
        $data = [ordered]@{}
        foreach($h in $headers) { $data[$h] = $null }
    }
}

$results | Export-Csv storage.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

Which pushes more work down into the regex engine, does less string processing and string interpolation, uses fewer variables and fewer cmdlets, avoids all the switch and break jumping around, and may run faster.

I haven't tested it, because I don't know the content of your file.